# .Net Reflection Property Info of a PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, generics, system.reflection, propertyinfo

I have a class structure like below,

```
Class A
{ 
     ClassB objB {get; set;}
     int data {get; set;}
}
Class B
{
     int x {get; set;}
     int data {get; set;}
}
```

Now I need to use reflection on Class A, to save a following input to Class A object (eg: input => data=10;x=15;data=20)

Problem: When I do this, PropertyInfo[] p = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties()

I get [objB, data] in p.

But I need to drill down to basic data types for any such above structure, that is I need something like,

[data (from Class A), x (from Class B), data (from Class B)] this is my first requirement

2nd requirement: Once I reach above requirement, how do I differentiate between data (from Class A) and data (from Class B).

Comment: Your design is wrong, probably.

Comment: Could you elaborate, how did you come down to using reflection? Maybe there is another way.

Comment: This is a web service, so there are several requests, now i need a generic approach so that based on the request type i will be able to build a request, instead of having buildReq for each reqtype..which is why i need reflection

Comment: If the requests are similar, I would use a request type in the request contract.  If they are calling different functions, then I suggest that you define separate requests - exposing what your service can do explicitly will help clients using the service API.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

You can write a recursive algorithm that runs through the properties of the first class and keeps on digging *while the property's type `property.PropertyType` is not one defined in a .NET assembly `property.PropertyType.Assembly`. So check the assembly or a list of types that you consider primitive.

Comment: Checking the assembly will fail if the one of the member is of type List<objB>, List belongs to mscorlib.dll but holds local assembly class...this really sucks...i was hoping there would be more straight forward approach

Comment: Also, I need copy values to primitive types set value to object, again do the same for parent objects, thats a pain

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use foreach loop on p.

Check the type of each item inside first foreach and if it matches typeOf(B) then do a propertyInfo on this particular item to get into class B properties.Now ,you can first set the properties of class B and then second property of A.